# Search Function does not filter all values

Tags: javascript, html, function, search, filter

I am working on a search function with a scroll-list on a webpage. Here is the JS I have:

```
function mysearchFunction() {

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("mysearchInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } 
        else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

and HTML

```
<th>
    <input type="text" id="mysearchInput" onkeyup="mysearchFunction()" placeholder="Search for location..." title="Location">
        <button onclick="mysearchFunction();">Search</button>
        <ul id="myUL">
        <li><a href="">IT</a><li>
        <li><a href="">Dragon's Room</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Door 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cafeteria </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dragons Den </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dragons Tail </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dragon </a></li>
        </ul>
</th>
</html>
```

The search function works, however it only filters until the first value. eg. If I search "dragon", and I have 3 dragons in the scroll list, it would produce a result of "Dragon, Car, Cat, Dragon1, Dragon2"
I am sorry if the question is too basic. I am still learning JS and web development, so I am not sure to to approach the problem.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Can you please add your example html code?

Comment: I just added the html snippet

Comment: Problem is the missing closing li tag: `<li><a href="">IT</a><li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just noticed what the problem is. Probably, your code has an error while executing `for` phrase because of empty `li`.

The following code will be working fine.

```
function mysearchFunction() {

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("mysearchInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

/***** updated code from here ******/
        if (a) {
          txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        } else {
          txtValue = '';
        }
/***** updated code to here ******/
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } 
        else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Allen. This solves the problem. However, I am not sure how breaking it down into an IF statement would make a difference?

Comment: @shvan If `li` hasn't `a` tag, variable `a` will be `undefined`. So it'll occur an error on `a.textContent` or `a.innerText`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue could be how you are calling the function.

Please see the working demo below which includes a click event on the button to trigger the function.

```js
function mysearchFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("mysearchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="mysearchInput" type="text" placeholder="search" />
<button onclick="mysearchFunction();">Search</button>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a>Dragon</a></li>
  <li><a>Car</a></li>
  <li><a>Cat</a></li>
  <li><a>Dragon1</a></li>
  <li><a>Dragon2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**
After OP shared there HTML, it was clear a missing closing tag was causing the issue:

```
<li><a href="">IT</a><li> // closing </li> needed
```

Comment: Your code runs in the snippet, however, I don't see, to get results in my html. Here's a copy of my html if it helps:

Comment: after reviewing your HTML, you are missing a closing tag on a li `<li><a href="">IT</a><li>`